Pen tool scroll
Working in grease pencil with a drawing table. Under the "tool" menu I see my "Brushes" and I use the mouse scroll wheel to scroll through the brushes. Is there a way to scroll through my brushes using my drawing pen (styles). It would be dreamy to use my styles to "tap" the brush menu and scroll through all my brushes and pick one with out putting down my pen.
In the below film, you can see a brush scroll using a wheel mouse. I want the same effect with my (styles, tablet pen)
https://capture.dropbox.com/yqxLLVVYNEpcMTJj

Hello, please provide screenshots so we have a better idea of what you're trying to achieve.
